# Rails 5 & Devise: Login always returns incorrect password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Fresh install of Devise, I'm able to register a new user. But after logging out, I can't login and devise returns "Invalid Email or password."

When I look at `User.last` I see the correct email. `User.last.password` is nil and `User.last.encrypted_password` returns an encrypted password.

Routes:

```
resources :users
devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: { sign_up: 'register', sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout'}
```

registrations/new:

```
    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: user_registration_path, :html => {:class => "col s12 form-text"}) do |f| %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <%= f.text_field :full_name, :class => "validate", :placeholder => "Robin Smith" %>

          <%= f.label :full_name, :class => "allcaps" %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <%= f.email_field :email, :class => "validate" %>
          <%= f.label :email, :class => "allcaps" %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <%= f.password_field :password, :class => "validate" %>
          <%= f.label :password, :class => "allcaps" %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="button-container">
        <%= f.submit :class => "waves-effect waves-light btn-flat", :value => "Join Now" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

sessions/new:

```
  <%= form_for :session, :html => {:class => "col s12 form-text"} do |f| %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <%= f.email_field :email, :class => "validate" %>
          <%= f.label :email, :class => "allcaps" %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <%= f.password_field :password, :class => "validate" %>
          <%= f.label :password, :class => "allcaps" %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="button-container">
        <%= f.submit :class => "waves-effect waves-light btn-flat", :value => "Login" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Looks like you modified the default sessions/new view that Devise generates. This is the default: `<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>` so make sure `:session` is doing what it's supposed to.

Comment: @mmichael thanks - just swapped to your version and it works. I incorrectly assumed I could just swap our resource for :session

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you'd like to keep this question and I'll add an answer based on my comment.

Comment: Yeah I think someone could find it useful despite being trivial :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you modified the default [sessions/new view](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb) that Devise generates.

This is the default:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

so make sure `:session` is doing what it's supposed to.